# C++...square series (same output each time)?

Tags: c++, class, function

Whenever I change the values in `s1.sqseries` the output never changes. It always remains 687194768. Why is that so?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cmath>
 #include<string>
 #include<iomanip>
 using namespace std;
 class square
 {
int a,b;
 public:
void sqseries(int x,int y)
{
    x=a;
    y=b;

    int c;
   for(c=a;c<=b;c++)
  {

   cout<<c*c<<endl;
  }
}
};
 int main ()
 {
  square s1;
  s1.sqseries(5,8);            /////////right here///////
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please indent your code consistently! It's hard to read it the way it looks right now.

Answer (score 5):

You need:

```
void sqseries(int x,int y)
{
    a=x;
    b=y;
    ...
}
```

Note that in your current code you just re-assign `x` and `y` with `a` and `b` inside your function thus the values being passed as function argument are never used but they just are overwritten with values of `a` and `b`.